# Update a json file from XLS file data

Tags: python, json, xls

Im trying to update a json file from XLS file data.
This what I wish to do :

- Extract namesFromJson
- Extract namesFromXLS
- for nameFromXLS in namesFromXLS :

  - Check if nameFromXLS is in namesFromJson :

    - if true : then :

      - extract xls row (of this name)
      - update jsonFile (of this name)

My problem is when its true, how can I update a jsonfile?

```
Python code:

    import xlrd
    import unicodedata
    import json

    intents_file = open("C:\myJsonFile.json","rU")
    json_intents_data = json.load(intents_file)

    book = xlrd.open_workbook("C:\myXLSFile.xlsx")
    sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
    row =""
    nameXlsValues = []
    intentJsonNames =[]

    for entity in json_intents_data["intents"]: 
        intentJsonName = entity["name"]
        intentJsonNames.append(intentJsonName)

    for row_index in xrange(sheet.nrows):
        nameXlsValue = sheet.cell(rowx = row_index,colx=0).value
        nameXlsValues.append(nameXlsValue)

        if nameXlsValue  in intentJsonNames:
           #here ,I have to extract row values from xlsFile and update jsonFile 
           for col_index in xrange(sheet.ncols):
               value = sheet.cell(rowx = row_index,colx=col_index).value
               if type(value) is unicode:
                     value = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD',value).encode('ascii','ignore')
                      row += "{0} - ".format(value)

my json file  is like this : 
{
 "intents": [
        {
            "id": "id1",
            "name": "name1",
            "details": {
                "tags": [
                    "tag1"
                ],
                "answers": [
                    {
                        "type": "switch",
                        "cases": [
                             {
                                "case": "case1",
                                "answers": [
                                    {
                                        "tips": [
                                            ""
                                        ],
                                        "texts": [
                                            "my text to be updated"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "case": "case2",
                                "answers": [
                                    {
                                        "tips": [
                                            "tip2"
                                        ],
                                        "texts": [
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "template": "json",
                "sentences": [
                    "sentence1",
                    " sentence2",
                    " sentence44"]
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "id2",
            "name": "name3",
            "details": {
                "tags": [
                    "tag2"
                ],
                "answers": [
                    {
                        "type": "switch",
                        "cases": [
                            {
                                "case": "case1",
                                "answers": [
                                    {
                                        "texts": [
                                          ""
                                        ]             
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "case": "case2",
                                "answers": [
                                    {
                                        "texts": [
                                            ""
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "sentences": [
                    "sentence44",
                    "sentence2"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]   
}
```

My xls file is like this :

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show us some content from both the json and xlxs? What exactly doesn't work? Also are you using python2.7?

Comment: My problem is how to update json file ( when nameFromXls is in namesFromJson)

Comment: Please put it in the question not the comments, and we also need example data from the xlxs.

Comment: It is possible to convert the XLS data file to Json format?

Comment: [https://pypi.org/project/excel2json-3/](https://pypi.org/project/excel2json-3/). Though I would recommend switching to python 3 as python 2 is about to be no longer supported.

Answer (score 0):

When you are loading the json data from file into memory it becomes a python dict named 'json_intents_data'.

When the condition 'if nameXlsValue  in intentJsonNames' is True you need to update the dict with the data you read from the Excel. (It looks like you know how to do it.)

When the loop 'for row_index in xrange(sheet.nrows):' is done, your dict is updated and you want to save it as a json file.

```
import json

with open('updated_data.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(json_intents_data, fp)
```